# How to start Qt development on Windows, but targeting Maemo 5?

Tags: windows, qt, nokia, maemo, qt-maemo

I've recently heard about Qt and read about how fun it is to develop with. By the way, I'm also buying a Nokia N900 and I heard that its operating system, Maemo 5, supports Qt quite nicely, so I thought I'll give it a shot.

I'm a .NET developer, so I'd prefer to develop on Windows, and if it is possible, using Visual Studio.
I downloaded the latest Qt SDK. I started up the Qt Creator and created a simple "Qt4 Gui Application". It was working fine, however, I couldn't find any options to compile for Maemo 5 anywhere.

Then, I downloaded the Visual Studio plugin and tried to create a "Qt Application" with that, however, no matter which Qt project type I chose, after clicking the OK button, the dialog just kept popping up again, so it couldn't create anything.

I also read about the Maemo 5 SDK, however, it only seems to work on Linux. (Every walkthrough for Windows started with setting up a virtual machine with Linux.) However, I'm not experienced with Linux at all, so I'd prefer to stay on Windows.

So my question is: is it possible to create Qt applications that will run on Maemo 5 while developing on Windows, or this is impossible?

Thank you in advance for any answers.

**EDIT (Solution):**

Since the time I started this question, a very nice development tool, the [Nokia Qt SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html) solves this problem very well. It is cross-platform and can be used to develop Symbian and Maemo apps alike. For the Maemo toolchain, it uses [MADDE](http://wiki.maemo.org/MADDE), which is exactly the tool recommended by the answer. (Note that it is no longer a technical preview anymore.)

[Here is a very nice introduction video about the Nokia Qt SDK.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39D-a3OU1Nk)

Comment: Visual Studio is a windows-specific development IDE. You'll have no luck developing for non-windows with it. Anyways, why do you want to develop for maemo, but work on a totally oposite OS-family. Using two OSs from closer families will help in lots of other ways, really.

Comment: @Hugo - Perhaps you didn't recognize, but I found a solution a long time ago. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest getting used to Linux; after all, Maemo (or MeeGo, now) is really Linux underneath, and the official SDK is the Linux-based scratchbox.

That being said, there exists an unofficial community project [MADDE](http://wiki.maemo.org/MADDE):

> This is a **TECHNICAL PREVIEW** of a new development tool for Maemo.  MADDE stands for Maemo Application Development and Debugging Environment and offers the following features:
>
> - Command-line cross-compiling
> - Multi-platform support (Linux (32-bit/64-bit), Windows, Mac OS X)
> - Configurable for different targets & toolchains
> - Client for the device to simplify the development process
> - Simplicity
>
> You are welcome to test the tool in your development process.  But keep in mind that this is a technical preview.  We highly appreciate your feedback in talk, the developer list and especially in bugzilla (Developer Platform -> MADDE).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!
I'm downloading MADDE right now. Sorry for the lame questions, but I'm pretty new to Qt. :)

Comment: Okay.
I obtained my N900 and had the time to play around it.
MADDE works pretty well.

Comment: @Venemo I've only got an n810 myself, but it's been very reliable and nice to develop for and use; I hope you enjoy your N900 :)

Comment: Yes, it has been very nice so far. :)
There is article about using Qt 4.6 for MADDE, which is quite good.
http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/02/11/qt-46-for-maemo-5-development-now-also-on-windows/